# SQL Server query to get first createdby value in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, greatest-n-per-group

`emp_record_change_log_tbl` has the following columns. I want the query to be like this, where "SQL code needed" will be the query to get the name of the person who entered the first record for a specific employee.

[image]

```sql
Select 
    change_id,
    Emp_ID,
    new salary,
    {sql code needed} as first_entered_by
from 
    emp_record_change_log_tbl
```

I know that at some point I will need a min function to first get the initial date.

But the result I am hoping for is to get John doe for employee 103 and Sarah Smith for employee 102.

Comment: [`FIRST_VALUE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/first-value-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)?

Comment: `MIN` is exactly what you need. But you will also need a `group by`.

Comment: sorry guys i am trying to edit my question so its more clear.

Comment: Potential duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6841605/20091109

Comment: Is your image that of your expected results, your sample dta, or a mix of both here?

Answer (score 2):

You can use 'CROSS APPLY' to do this.

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.Emp_ID, last_modifiedby, last_modifieddate
FROM emp_record_change_log_tbl t
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 last_modifiedby, last_modifieddate
             FROM emp_record_change_log_tbl
             WHERE Emp_ID = t.Emp_ID
             ORDER BY last_modifieddate ASC) ca
```

If you have an `Employee` table with a `PRIMARY KEY` you don't need the `DISTINCT`.

```
SELECT t.Emp_ID, last_modifiedby, last_modifieddate
FROM employee t
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 last_modifiedby, last_modifieddate
             FROM emp_record_change_log_tbl
             WHERE Emp_ID = t.Emp_ID
             ORDER BY last_modifieddate ASC) ca
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using MIN I would use subquery, TOP and ORDER BY. Here is how  it would look for your example:

```
SELECT change_id, Emp_ID, NewSalary, 
(SELECT TOP(1) LastModifiedBy 
FROM emp_record_change_log_tbl 
WHERE Emp_Id = mainTable.Emp_Id 
ORDER BY LastModifiedDate) AS first_entered_by
FROM emp_record_change_log_tbl AS mainTable
```